# trying to manage the value of 2 inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not really good for speaking english, but this problem could kill me.. I'm on since 3 days..

I have 2 inputs, each input can be 1 to 100. 
But i need that the addition of the both is never below 100. 
Exemple : 40 & 60, 30 & 70, ...

I tried to change the second input with a focusout (rly that i need), to add to the second input the value that i needed. 
Exemple : 
Input 1 : value 40
Input 2 : Value 20 (In this case i need that this input change to 60 whenever i focusout it)

Sorry for this poor english, but instead of reading a solution this time i need to post (Never posted before because i always find what i needed ).

This is my code :

```
if($("#coemp_pret1").val() == "1"){
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        var tempValue = $(this).val($(this).val() + $("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1").val());

        if( tempValue < "100" ){            
            return value
                .replace(/\d{1,2}(?!\d)|100/, "");

            $(this).val(100 - $("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1").val());
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks i hope you can help me, byebye !

Comment: What are these two elements: `$("#coemp_pret1")` `$("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1")`, better have snippet

Comment: $("#coemp_pret1") is a trigger (he is actually working)
$("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1") is the first input !
What is a snippet ? :D (i search it but if you have more information i would take it)

Comment: is the input text input or a dropdown?

Comment: Can you explain what you code does? I can't really read it

Comment: FYI, the line `$(this).val(100 - $("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1").val());` will be ignored since you have a return just before. In a function, the `return`statement stop the execution of the function.

Comment: in `tempValue < "100"`, 100 is in quotation marks. Is it supposed to be? Otherwise its a string, not a number/integer

Comment: @sphinx It's a text input with regex, these input can be set to 1 to 100.

Stardust : Actually, nearly nothing, it just delete the second input when i focusout it.

Karl-AndréGagnon Merci, c'est la base mais je l'avais zappé. J'y était presque j'arrivais à changer pour avoir une valeur de 100 mais pas entre 100 et 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a new event, to handle first input changes. So, everytime you `change` the value from it, the value from the second will reset to ''.

Also added `.on('blur')` event for the second field, so you can check if the sum of both is below 100. If it is, then the difference from 100 and the sum will be extracted to be displayed as the second input value.

Code below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#inp1').on('change', function() {
    $('#inp2').val('');
  });

  $('#inp2').on('blur', function() {
    var val1 = $('#inp1').val();

    if (val1 > 0) {
      var val2 = $(this).val();
      var sum = (val1 + val2);

      if (sum < 100) {
        var diff = (100 - sum);
        $(this).val(diff);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Value 1</span>
<input id="inp1" type="text" />
<br />
<br />
<span>Value 2</span>
<input id="inp2" type="text" />
```

Comment: This is what i need ! But in your code i just have to change this line : var sum = (val1 + val2); to var sum = var1; (I know it's dumb ) Then the addition of the both number always do 100 can i fix it ? (Because with val1 + val2 i'm having some problem like (input 1 : 40 input 2 : 20 ( then change to 40) because sum = 60 and then 100-60=40

Comment: it's OK : Just have to change this line var diff = String(100 - val1); SO THANK YOU DUDE FOR THIS I LOVE U !

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'blur' event on the second input & `keyup` on first input.

`blur` will start calculation as soon as focus is removed from the second input.
On updating first input the second field will set to empty

```js
$("#coemp_pret1").on("keyup", function() {
  $("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1").val("");
});
$("#QuotDecAdh_s3p1").on("blur", function() {
  if ("" !== $("#coemp_pret1").val() && ($(this).val(), 100 > $(this).val() + $("#coemp_pret1").val())) {
    var a = 100 - $("#coemp_pret1").val();
    $(this).val(a);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="coemp_pret1">
<input type="text" id="QuotDecAdh_s3p1">
```

Comment: I will try to adapt this. Thanks i will be back soon to keep you aware of the situation.